# Lua - Get current day?

Tags: date, time, lua

I do not know where to ask about this kinda stuff so I thought why not ask Stackoverflow?

I wonder if it's possible to get the current day somehow, with Lua?

Something about os.date() but I have no idea how to do it. Or maybe os.time() ?

like:

```
local day = os.time()somethingsomething
```

And then check

```
if (day == 'monday') then
print('It is monday')
elseif (day == 'tuesday') then
print('It is tuesday!')
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not to Google it? There is an excelent article here. See http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html

Try `print(os.date("%A"))` for getting day of week.

To check if it's monday now you can write any of those conditions.

```
if (os.date("%A") == "Monday") then
  print("It's Monday")
end
if (os.date("*t").wday == 1) then
  print("It's Monday")
end
```

Comment: But how can I make a check if today is friday or monday for example?

Comment: @user3036459 This is trivial, as you see. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the named days:

```
local daysoftheweek={"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thrusday","Friday","Saturday"}
local day=daysoftheweek[os.date("*t").wday]
print(day)
```

Or you can just use `os.date("*t").wday` and it will return 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, etc.